# Maven Eclipse error after drive mapping change

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, maven-plugin

I have H:/ mapped to \abc5565\share (example here) and able to build maven project in eclipse with repository in my user's .m2 folder. Recently my employer changed mapping to \abc5565\shd$. After this mapping of H:\ starting getting below errors of cached repository:

```
   No plugin found for prefix 'war' in the current project and in the plugin groups [] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\anucha\.m2\repository), central (http://reposerver:8180/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/)] pom.xml
```

OR
     org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (execution: default-compile, phase: compile)    pom.xml
    line 1  Maven Java EE Configuration Problem

and many more....

Note: Good part is I can map back to \abc5565\share but remapping every time after login is not convenient and it may go anytime. I tried repository deletion, creating local repository in H: drive, creating new workspace in new mapped drive from scratch but still getting errors.

Comment: Open the `%userprofile%\.m2\settings.xml`file and see what path is on property `localRepository`.

Comment: post the complete error stack.